# How to create and return an Expression<Func 

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, lambda

I Use entity Framework 4.
I would like to be able to create a function that return an Expression func that will be use in a lambda expression.

```
  var ViewModel = _db.Suppliers.Select(model => new { 
                model,SupType = model.SupplierType.SupplierTypeTexts.Where( st => st.LangID == 1)   
            });
```

I would like to  make this call like that

```
  var ViewModel = _db.Suppliers.Select(model => new { 
                model,SupType = model.SupplierType.GetText() 
            });
```

My Partial class is:

```
  public partial class SupplierType
    {

       public  Expression<Func<SupplierTypeText, bool>> GetText()
        {
            return p => p.LangID == 1;
        }
```

How can i perform this.

Comment: I updated my answer based on this. Please check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy. For example, Let's assume you have a *Product* table that is mapped to *Products* EntitySet in your context, now you want to pass a predicate and select a *Product*:

```
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> GetPredicate(int id) {
    return (p => p.ProductID == id);
}
```

You can call *GetPredicate()* with a Product ID to filter based on that:

```
var query = ctx.Products.Where(GetPredicate(1)).First();
```

The point really is that you can always pass a Lambda Expression to where an Expression<T> is needed.

**EDIT:**

You should change your code like this:

```
var ViewModel = _db.Suppliers.Select(model => new { 
    model,
    SupType = model.SupplierType.SupplierTypeTexts.Where(GetText()) 
});
```

```
public Expression<Func<SupplierTypeText, bool>> GetText() {
    return (stt => stt.LangID == 1);
}
```

Comment: Oh nice, I try your solution, but that gave me an error like that. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[MySite.Models.Supplier,System.Boolean]] GetText()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: So, your error is because of the GetText() method. Please share your code and I'll fix it up for you or let me know what is your exact scenario and I'll change my code accordingly.

Comment: I made an update of my post. @Morteza Thanks for your support

Comment: It's a multilangual website, I want to get  the text based on the client language choice. For now I hardcoded the language ID.

Comment: No problem. Ok, you cannot call GetText() on SupplierType, you should only pass GetText() when a predicate is required. Please have a look at my edited answer and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: Where should I put the GetText() Method ?

Comment: It depends on your design, but this type of methods typically belong to the Repository class where you shape your queries. I can see that you put it in the SupplierType partial class which does not seems right to me unless you are following an "Active Record" design pattern. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's working perfecly. And I put the get text in my repository where it's should be

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically create compiled Expression at runtime (as opposed to ones hardcoded against a particular data model at compile time) you need to use the static methods on the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) class.